# load static and DOCTYPE html position in django views

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django and have trouble understanding the difference between the position of lines shown below:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

In the above code, the PyCharm shows error but if I change the position as shown below, it works as intended:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
```

Can anyone explain how this works or if I am doing it the wrong way? Thanks!!

Comment: [`DOCTYPE` is one of the first elements to appear in an HTML document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#writing), so you can't put any HTML before it.

Comment: Thanks @ForceBru I wondered that but most of the documentation writes the load static code before the DOCTYPE line, that's why I was confused. Thanks for clearing up!

Comment: I don't think it's even necessary to use `DOCTYPE`. It'll _technically_ be invalid HTML, but browsers are basically specifically built to handle invalid HTML (because a lot of HTML is _technically_ invalid nowadays), so it'll be fine

Comment: personally i add load static on top

Comment: Yeah, it kind of organizes your code a bit. Any particular reason @SerioUs for using it?

Comment: I think it's more better to put your {% extends %} and {% load static or template_tags %} before your html tags, it will be more cleaner and standard.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an extension named "Django templates" in your vs-code or any other editor you are using.
[[image: check the correct name of Extension and author]
After This: Your Code will look like this with No warning:-
[image: Image after installing extension]